# Evaluating surface integrals in calc

Tags: calculus

Looking to find the following surface integral:

$\int\int_s yzdS $ where $ S $ is the part of the plane $ x+y+z=1$ that lies in the first octant

looking for some help with this problem

Answer (score 2):

Since are integrating our a function of $y,z,$ project the surface onto the $yz$ plane.

The surface is a plane that is at an angle to the yz plane, and there is $\sqrt 3$ units of area on the surface for ever unit of area in the projection.

$dS = \sqrt 3 \:dA\\
\int_0^1\int_0^{1-z} yz \sqrt 3 \:dy\,dz$

Since you are complaining about the integration :)

$\sqrt 3\int_0^1 \frac 12 y^2z  \:dz |_0^{1-z}\\
\frac {\sqrt 3}{2} \int_0^1 z - 2z^2 + z^3\:dz \\
\frac {\sqrt 3}{2}( \frac 12 z^2 - \frac 23 z^3 + \frac 14 z^4) |_0^1\\
\frac {\sqrt 3}{2}( \frac 12 - \frac 23 + \frac 14)\\
\frac {\sqrt 3}{24}$

Comment: hmm okay so i just need to evaluate this integral now?

Comment: Provided you sort of understand what I did in the set-up, yes.

Comment: so integrate for y then plug in the limits of 1-z and 0 then integrate for z and plug in the limits of 1 and 0?

Comment: Carry on and find an actual numerical value; this might be a little tricky...

Comment: yes nasty integration

Comment: It shouldn't get to messy,  there will be a string of rather simple fractions ($\frac 12, \frac 13, \frac 14, \frac 16$) and you add and subtract and should bet something like $\frac 1{12}$ or $\frac 1{24}$.

Comment: Ha. I got 1/24 (see my answer below).

Comment: awesome so both answers work then?

Answer (score 0):

Consider planes parallel to the $yz$-plane. The part of the integral on the plane $x=a$ is
$$\int_0^{1-a}x(1-a-x)dx=\frac16(1-a)^3$$
Then the entire integral is
$$\int_0^1\frac16(1-a)^3da=\frac1{24}$$

Comment: This is incorrect. You're not thinking about the tilt of the plane.

Comment: Then how can I correct it?

Comment: Learn about surface integrals? Also, I presume you mean $x$ to be $y$ or $z$ in the first integral.

Comment: @TedShifrin Wait a minute. If I divide my integral by sqrt(3) like in the other answer, can I use composing integrals?